# Border does not show for expander in popup

Tags: wpf

Not sure what I'm doing wrong: but for some reason I cannot make the Expander control show its border even though I have specified it in the XAML.

Can someone help me get the border to show up.

[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
<Popup x:Name="PopLink" StaysOpen="True" Placement="Mouse" PopupAnimation="Fade" AllowsTransparency="True" MaxWidth="300">
        <Popup.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Popup">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="OnPopupMouseLeave"></EventSetter>
            </Style>
        </Popup.Style>

        <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Esri_BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="2" Background="{DynamicResource Esri_ControlBackgroundBrush}">

            <StackPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10 10 5 0" Text="{Binding PopupDesc}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
                    <Button BorderThickness="0" Margin="0 -1 0 0 " x:Name="ButtonClosePopup" Click="ButtonClosePopup_OnClick" Width="15"  Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="X"></Button>
                </DockPanel>

                <Separator Margin="10 10 10 5"/>

                <TextBlock Margin="10 3 10 5" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding PopupTitle}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10 3 10 5" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding PopupAuthors}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10 5 10 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PopupText}"></TextBlock>
                
                <Expander BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="{Binding IsPopupAbstractVisible}" Header="Abstract" Margin="10 5" >
                    <TextBlock Height="100" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="150" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=PopupAbstract}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="0"></TextBox>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Expander>

                <TextBlock Margin="10 0 10 10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PopupKeywords}" FontStyle="Italic"></TextBlock>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

Comment: it is likely there si a problem with DynamicResource `BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Esri_BorderBrush}"`

Comment: I tried this and it worked ok.  However, as I understand the expander button has a circle surrounding it that I do not see - is there a control template that is does this and is affecting the border?  Also, you have the `TextBox` for the expander nested in a `TextBlock` which may not be what you want.

Comment: I took the ESRI brushes out but still have a borderless expander.

Comment: I actually think this an ESRI problem - if I just have a plain WPF project - you can see the borders fine.